# OutofMemory Exception happened in Spark SQL Join

Tags: join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use Spark SQL module in Spark 2.0.

I got OutOfMemory Exception when running Spark SQL Join queries. 
these are my problem details:

I generated two tables(rankings and uservisits, saved as txt file) for testing.schema as following

```
rankings( 
  pageURL STRING, 
  pageRank INT, 
  avgDuration INT ) 

uservisits ( 
  sourceIP STRING, 
  destURL STRING, 
  visitDate STRING, 
  adRevenue DOUBLE, 
  userAgent STRING, 
  countryCode STRING, 
  languageCode STRING, 
  searchWord STRING, 
  duration INT )
```

rankings has 10000 columns, uservisits has 15000000 columns. 
uservisits is skewed data,70 percent of records have the same value in desURL field

when i used the Join command as follows

```
SELECT pagerank,sourceIP ,pageURL ,adrevenue 
    from **uservisits** 
    INNER JOIN **rankings** 
    ON pageURL=destURL 
    order by adrevenue desc
```

it ran successfully without exception.

but when i swapped two tables like this(rankings and uservisits are swapped):

```
SELECT pagerank,sourceIP ,pageURL ,adrevenue 
    from **rankings**
    INNER JOIN **uservisits** 
    ON pageURL=destURL 
    order by adrevenue desc
```

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

exception happened.

After that, i did some join queries testing like these ,it seems like for skewed data,small table join big table will get exception ,but big table join small table won't.

i feel confused about it. Can anyone tell me why these problems happen?

Thanks!